# How to disable the form extend tab in run time?

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6

While running the Project, we cannot able to extend the form.

In run time, we put the mouse pointer in the Project form Layout border, it showing <-->.

It should not show to extend the form in the run time.

Am New to VB 6, How to write a code or set a condition?

Need VB 6 help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the BorderStyle property of your form from **Sizable** (default) to anyone of the fixed variations (for instance **Fixed Single**).

Here's a screenshot of the property that controls this behaviour:

[image]

Comment: +1 Here is a link to the VB6 manual topic on BorderStyle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245047(VS.60).aspx